# Querying POCO's with References

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have the following (simplified) datamodel:

```
public class Order : IHasId<long>
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Material))]
    public long MaterialId { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public Material Material { get; set; }
}

public class Material : IHasId<long>
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to populate `Order.Material` with the material referenced by `MaterialId`, is there a way to achieve that in a simple way? The [Load APIs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#querying-pocos-with-references) seem to do something similar, but in the inverse situation (when the reference is on `Material`, not on `Order`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [Self References](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#self-references) in OrmLite and works with your above example:

```
public class Order : IHasId<long>
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Material))]
    public long MaterialId { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public Material Material { get; set; }
}

public class Material : IHasId<long>
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

db.Insert(new Material { Name = "A" });
db.Insert(new Material { Name = "B" });

db.Insert(new Order {
    MaterialId = 2,
});

var order = db.LoadSingleById<Order>(1);

order.PrintDump();
```

Recursively print object graph to Output:

```
{
    Id: 1,
    MaterialId: 2,
    Material: 
    {
        Id: 2,
        Name: B
    }
}
```

Comment: also, is there a way to configure deeper nesting? on the documentation it says it nests only to first level

Comment: @GiacomoTagliabue The `Load*` API's are specifically for loading references yes, use standard API's when you don't want to load references. The POCO's are disconnected and only supports 1-level of nesting.

Comment: Thank you. What you do with ServiceStack is simply AWESOME, best C# open source project that I know :)

Comment: @GiacomoTagliabue np :) + thx, appreciate the positive feedback!